# Why does this object initialization work?

Tags: javascript

I do a classical JavaScript object initialization like this, it works like a charm:

```
function Hero(a, n) {                                                            
    this.nom = a;                                                                
    this.job = n;                                                                
    this.quiSuisJe = function() {
        return "Mon nom est "+this.nom+" et je suis un "+this.job;
    } 
}                                                                                
var x = new Hero("Joe", "Ninja");                                                
var y = new Hero("Jinx", "Carry AD");                                            
console.log(x.quiSuisJe());                                                      
console.log(y.quiSuisJe());
```

But if I change the `quiSuisJe` function like this:

```
function Hero(a, n) {                                                            
    this.nom = a;                                                                
    this.job = n;                                                                
    this.quiSuisJe = function() {
        return "Mon nom est "+a+" et je suis un "+n;
    } 
}                                                                                
var x = new Hero("Joe", "Ninja");                                                
var y = new Hero("Jinx", "Carry AD");                                            
console.log(x.quiSuisJe());                                                      
console.log(y.quiSuisJe());
```

It works. Why?

Comment: Closure. The inner function is closure, it has access to the parent function vars. Also note that the inner function is created for each instance.

Comment: Now try `x.nom = "qwerty"; x. quiSuisJe();` in both and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A constructor is still a function, so since you've declared a function within it, you essentially create a closure. This means that inside this new function you have access to properties of top-level function. Of course, just because you DO have access to it, doesn't mean you should use it like this. Try to use `this` instead, like you have in your first example.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer, but I still dont know why those variables are not destroyed. I understand why dynamic declared variable are not destroyed (why they can't) if they are used within a following "inner" function (variable scoping), but the problem here is that they are **not** declared like `var a ="blabla", b="blibli";` but they are *parameters*... I think I'm missing something.

Comment: You can pretty much consider parameters to be `var a= 'blabla'` placed at the very top of the function.